# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis at the bottom of code - why? Syntax is good

Tags: sql, oracle, select

```
select racuni.str_id
  from racuni
  where racuni.str_id in
                   (select racuni.str_id
                      from racuni 
                           join stavke
                           on (racuni.racuni_id = stavke.rcn_id)
                     group by racuni.str_id
                     order by sum(stavke.iznos_kamate) desc
                    )
    and rownum = 1;
```

Comment: The `group by` + `order by` in the subquery are useless.

Comment: Hm, but I don't know how to get the highest sum for that select...

Comment: An `in` subquery returns a pure set. A set does not have an order. Your intention is not very clear; you just want to find the str_id with the largest sum (stavke.iznos_kamate) ? (in that case you'll probably need `HAVING` in the subquery)

Comment: First i made it like this:
having max(sum(stavke.iznos_kamate))  -- but problem again occured because it was nested too deeply

Answer (score 1):

You must first do an order by in the innermost query, then select the first row in the inner query, and then get that racun in the outer query. Like this:

```
select racuni.*
from   racuni
where  racuni.str_id in
             (select str_id
              from
               (select racuni.str_id
                  from racuni 
                       join stavke
                       on (racuni.racuni_id = stavke.rcn_id)
                 group by racuni.str_id
                 order by sum(stavke.iznos_kamate) desc )
               where rownum = 1 );
```

Comment: Hi friend, what if I'm trying to use this:
select rcn_id, var_for_sum
     from
     ( select soa.rcn_id, sum(soa.iznos_kamate)
..... some code)
rcn_id i can use, but hwo can I use sum??